# Yo boy, must it sum

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, palindrome, integer-partitions

> Every positive integer can be expressed as the sum of at most three palindromic positive integers in any base *b*≥5.   [Cilleruelo et al., 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06208)

A positive integer is *palindromic* in a given base if its representation in that base, without leading zeros, reads the same backwards. In the following, *only* base *b*=10 will be considered.

The decomposition as a sum of palindromic numbers is *not unique*. For example, `5` can be expressed directly as `5`, or as the sum of `2, 3`. Similarly, `132` can be decomposed as `44, 44, 44` or as `121, 11`.

### The challenge

Given a positive integer, produce its sum decomposition into three or fewer positive integers that are palindromic in base 10.

### Additional rules

- The algorithm used should work for arbitrarily large inputs. However, it is acceptable if the program is limited by memory, time or data type restrictions.
- Input and output can be taken by [any reasonable means](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). Input and output format is flexible as usual.
- You can choose to produce one or more valid decompositions for each input, as long as the output format is unambiguous.
- [Programs or functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398) are allowed, in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073). [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Examples

Since an input can have many decompositions, these are examples rather than test cases. Each decomposition is shown on a different line.

```
Input  ->  Output

5     ->   5
           2, 3

15    ->   1, 3, 11
           9, 6

21    ->   11, 9, 1
           7, 7, 7

42    ->   22, 11, 9
           2, 7, 33

132   ->   44, 44, 44
           121, 11

345   ->   202, 44, 99
           2, 343

1022  ->   989, 33
           999, 22, 1

9265  ->   9229, 33, 3
           8338, 828, 99
```

Comment: mmm, pun in the title

Comment: I wonder: is there any integer that *must* be composed into two palindromes? This would make a nice test case (if not, hey, golfers can use this fact and only check `k=1` and `k=3`.)

Comment: @Lynn Seems "unlikely", as there turn out to be quite a few decompositions for each input. But as we know, intuition in maths can be so misleading...

Comment: @Lynn If you're allowing `k=1` (as in the original number is already a palindrome), that means you're assuming the other 2 numbers are both 0.  So if 0 is acceptable as one of the numbers, any number which must be done with `k=2` would also work for `k=3` if one of the three numbers is 0.

Comment: I don't think there's any numbers that can ONLY be expressed as a sum of 2. Therefore, you can just cover the 3 and 1 case and ignore 2.

Comment: @SteadyBox interesting... "For all palindromic numbers `p(n)` there exists `p(i)+p(j)=p(n)`, where `p(x)` is the set of all palindromic numbers?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
~+ℕᵐ.↔ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v077UcvUh1sn6D1qmwKk/v@3NDIz/R8FAA)

Surprisingly not that slow.

#### Explanation

```
(?)~+  .          Output is equal to the Input when summed
     ℕᵐ.          Each element of the Output is a positive integer
       .↔ᵐ(.)     When reversing each element of the Output, we get the Output
```

Comment: What's with the random `.`'s in the explanation, and the `(.)`? Don't really know Brachylog.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn `.` is the output variable. `~+`, `ℕᵐ`, and `↔ᵐ` are predicates which have a left and right variable. The duplication of those `.` simply indicates that the output is involved directly in each of those 3 predicate calls. The final `(.)` is here to display that the output variable is implicitely the last variable of the program. Therefore, the last stated relationship is really `.↔ᵐ.` which means *"mapping reverse on the output results in the output"*.

Comment: Very good at last the input  could be >10000

Comment: It's surprising that negative numbers can be considered palindromes (thus requiring `ℕᵐ`).

Comment: @DLosc That’s because [`↔` is implemented to reverse digits only](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/blob/master/src/predicates.pl#L327). They wouldn’t be palindromes if we treated them as strings, but this would greatly reduce expressivity in Brachylog.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>82</s> 79 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:min([f(n-k)+[k]for k in range(1,n+1)if`k`==`k`[::-1]]or[[]],key=len)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDRa9swEMafo7/ioA@1WyfUTjKoqQdlrGDW9mHLyzCm1ZJzImxJniRvpKV/e3qSs5XB6IMO7tPd7zu@fu92WmWHxmgJBq0ezBpByF4bB2csyHZv3xS2wQYkSi2eMGrinE18AwU8v7CJ/9th16OJlP@aiAYUKO1AqLDktbBQqZp2GhojxaAbzDhAOvvTj6TR0aF10Zmv1oMbbQhM0KB4am@EcnD6nC9eYPqRrjmd0ZDkLlJJ8IkPTdFx@WPDQeVSqKgiddrG51Vbe1zrcYarLUZpos7TWDSP7WNRUKnyfJrWtTZVVddJi/uiQxUfTuCG9qzkXUe7/eAsOcFvbVoLnCKzMxbOXiaQ0svSmLETuOVmi@a4QJH/HITBY6LcCa1mrKFo3iIeIYuMKHMq88UycD7/QgXdf2EcdmK7I93gejCWmNAJKdyMWXR/tSBFKVxdwfzi6JJeZFmgX6sN4DsOPvy1QW5xA9bxdQuWrh0NRvDX2/KuXD18W11/@pJAaB/K@5vyvlx9T@CfNj66X2YflvHhFQ)

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ŒṗDfU$ṪḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7p7ukhao83Lnq4Y6e/4fbHzWtcf//31RHwRCITYwA)

#### How it works

```
ŒṗDfU$ṪḌ  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

Œṗ        Find all integer partitions of n.
  D       Convert each integer in each partition to base 10.
     $    Combine the two links to the left into a chain.
    U     Upend; reverse all arrays of decimal digits.
   f      Filter the original array by the upended one.
      Ṫ   Take the last element of the filtered array.
          This selects  the lexicographically smallest decomposition of those with
          the minimal amount of palindromes.
       Ḍ  Undecimal; convert all arrays of decimal digits to integers.
```

Comment: I just wanted to submit a solution with ~140 bytes, then I see 8 bytes and I'm like: "Nope, not gonna post mine".

Comment: Comparing scores across languages is pretty much meaningless. I've posted [a Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146137/12012) myself, not because it has a chance to beat this answer, but because it's the shortest *Python* answer I can think of.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 117 bytes

```python
def f(n):p=[x for x in range(n+1)if`x`==`x`[::-1]];print[filter(None,[a,b,n-a-b])for a in p for b in p if n-a-b in p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBCsMgEAXQq8xSqS7StBuLV@gFRIhSpx0oo4gLc3qb2M3nfz68srdP5usYr4SAgqUp1nXAXKEDMdTA7yT4skjCrW/WHuGM0Yv3j1KJm0P6tlTFM3NSLqioWAcdvTyJcBJlavFfCWH@c/mBYr3d5fgB)

Prints a list of lists, each of which is a solution. Rod saved 9 bytes.

Comment: [-9 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcxBCsMgEAXQq8xSqS7StBuLV@gFRIhSpx0oo4gLc3qb2M3nfz68srdP5usYr4SAgqUp1nXAXKEDMdTA7yT4skjCrW/WHuGM0Yv3j1KJm0P6tlTFM3NSLqioWAcdvTyJcBJlavFfCWH@c/mBYr3d5fgB) switching to function, replacing `c` with subtractions and using `filter`

Comment: @Rod Thanks! `filter(None` hit me as well while I was making dinner, haha. `c → n-a-b` is cool :)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>115</s> ... <s>84</s> 83 bytes

Always returns a three-element array, where unused entries are padded with zeros.

```js
f=(n,b=a=0)=>(r=[b,a%=n,n-a-b]).some(a=>a-[...a+''].reverse().join``)?f(n,b+!a++):r
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,b=a=0)=>(r=[b,a%=n,n-a-b]).some(a=>a-[...a+''].reverse().join``)?f(n,b+!a++):r

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(5)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(15)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(21)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(42)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(132)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(345)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(1022)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(9265)))
```

Answer (score 6):

## R, 126 bytes <s>145 bytes</s>

Thanks to Giuseppe for golfing off 19 bytes

```
function(n){a=paste(y<-0:n)
x=combn(c(0,y[a==Map(paste,Map(rev,strsplit(a,"")),collapse="")]),3)
unique(x[,colSums(x)==n],,2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrLCsIwEADv/YyedmGFVG/ifoInj6WHGCIE0k3MQ1LEb4/W2wwzqTfujyqmuCAg@NYcdS4WtstBnQWHxiasdwEDirZZM191hP9COyX7olxSjt4V0DSOiGSC9zpmyz9bkE44VHHPaqHNe7vVNUNDZlmIjvjpDSY1Yf8C)

Explanation

R does not have a native way to reverse strings and many default string operations don't work on numbers. So first we convert the series of positive integers (plus 0) to characters.

Next we produce a vector of 0 and all palindromes.  The string reversal requires splitting each number up by characters, reversing the order of the vector and pasting them back together with no gap.

Next I want to check all groups of three (here's where the 0s are important), luckily R has a built in combination function which returns a matrix, each column in a combination.

I apply the `colSums` function to the matrix and keep only the elements which equal the supplied target.

Finally, because there are two 0s, any set of two positive integers will be duplicated so I use a unique function on the columns.

The output is a matrix where each column is a set of positive, pallindromic integers that sum to the target value. It is lazy and returns 0's when fewer than 3 elements are used.

Comment: [128 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYrLCsIwEADv/YyedmGFRm/ifoInj6WHGCIE0k3MQ1LEb4/W2wwzqTfujyqmuCAg@NYcdS4WtstBnQWHxiasdwEDE020zZr5qiP8J9op2RflknL0roCmcUQkE7zXMVv@2YJ0wqGKe1YLbd7bra4ZGjLLQnTET2@gJoX9Cw "R – Try It Online"). +1, though, nice use of `Map` to generate palindromes!

Comment: oops, found a [126 byter](https://tio.run/##HYrLCsIwEADv/YyedmGFVG/ifoInj6WHGCIE0k3MQ1LEb4/W2wwzqTfujyqmuCAg@NYcdS4WtstBnQWHxiasdwEDirZZM191hP9COyX7olxSjt4V0DSOiGSC9zpmyz9bkE44VHHPaqHNe7vVNUNDZlmIjvjpDSY1Yf8C "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
#~IntegerPartitions~3~Select~AllTrue@PalindromeQ&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7CoAwDADQqxQEL1AdhTq6VXQTh1BTDfQDMa69enwvgzyYQSiARjMZ7dpSBG9kDywkVMvbbNswYZA2p7Tzh85DonJxzbj26pmKGBcPO4yn/g)

returns all solutions

-2~MartinEnder~bytes

Comment: `#~IntegerPartitions~3~Select~AllTrue@PalindromeQ&`, I think?

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
RŒḂÐfṗ3R¤YS⁼³$$Ðf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o6KSHO5oOT0h7uHO6cdChJZHBjxr3HNqsogIU@v//v4kRAA)

-6 bytes thanks to HyperNeutrino.

Outputs all ways. However the output consists of some duplicates.

Comment: There's an `is palindrome` builtin lol

Comment: Also, if you use normal (raised) range, you can remove your last 4 bytes

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o6KSHO5oOT0h7uHO6cdChJZHBtoeWArn)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Still can beat neither Dennis nor Erik. Anyway am I going to decrypt _truncated_ Deflate-compressed Base64-encoded URL?

Comment: @user202729 Huh, must not have copied the link correctly. The code was `RŒḂÐfṗ3R¤YS⁼¥Ðf`

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
L<4aŒḂ€Ạ
ŒṗÇÐf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/HxiTx6KSHO5oeNa15uGsBF5C9c/rh9sMT0v4fbgdxZvz/b2gKAA)

Very, *very* inefficient.

Comment: Seems too much slow, even if the target is code length, for me it is not only the length

Comment: @RosLuP Here you don't aim to keep the code efficient, here you aim to shorten the code as much as possible. It has to work *in theory*, not necessarily in practice, since this is a [tag:code-golf] challenge, not a [tag:code-golf] [tag:restricted-complexity] or [tag:code-golf] [tag:restricted-time] challenge.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
#Dð*3ç⁇Σ³E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/X9nl8AYt48PLHzW2n1t8aLPr//@GpgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>90</s> <s>86</s> 79 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to Laikoni!

```hs
f=filter
h n=[f(>0)t|t<-mapM(\_->f(((==)<*>reverse).show)[0..n])"123",sum t==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCsIwEADAu69Yioes2FArFoRufuALapEcNiSYxJKsevHvccbb@uQYW3PkQhQuOw@ZFqfMgPKTuU92u6n7ozdOKUWE88EU/nCpjLr61xeXQeu8Yncaz92xvhMIUV5bsiEDwVZCFtiDh@t4mdof)

Returns a list of all solutions with some duplication.

Comment: 79 bytes with `mapM` and declaring `f=filter`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCsIwEADAu69Yioes2FArFoRufuALapEcNiSYxJKsevHvccbb@uQYW3PkQhQuOw@ZFqfMgPKTuU92u6n7ozdOKUWE88EU/nCpjLr61xeXQeu8Yncaz92xvhMIUV5bsiEDwVZCFtiDh@t4mdof "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 185 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=0,j=n,k;++i<=--j;)if(p(i))for(k=0;k<=j-k;k++)if(p(k)&p(j-k))return new int[]{j-k,k,i};return n;}
boolean p(int n){return(""+n).equals(""+new StringBuffer(""+n).reverse());}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFNT@MwEL33V4w4IJt8qJSCRN10xUqLxAFxgBvi4AaHdT7sYI@7QlF@e5k6XXYlDknG743fmzep5U5mtlemfm32uuutQ6gJywPqNq@CKVFbk5@J2TeSsFkftq0uoWyl93AvtYFhBnBEPUqkz87qV@iIY4/otHl7fgHp3jyPrQBG/Yk3GT@c7wzeHk3XD9talbiBLnjU6EMHBexNthkq65g2CLqYp3Vh0kYkiV4XWVYLrivWM835oacp5qJZF3XWiCZJJqrhpz0jhHOnMDgT/Uns@WUgNG1SPYq/jBjF1tpWSQN9NDR8mDh2cpIYnqv3IFsfD6QyxfsZqkq5Y4NTO@W8YpyLcS9i3il1dARUHj2lGuA8hcsUzulZULlcUH1Br4vlAZ0vqLxeXF3COGncOCc/fO7RKdmxqMIjAZB3sn@ytDr2tbb/KWazjSV3@jemVLaaBvlxFEQ7ZWAswtzylf0H8i8hWu4vWf5mjx8eVZfbgKtVTz3YGj5NOMZJx9m4/wQ)

Remove 1 byte from TIO to get the correct amount because the submission doesn't contain the `;` after the lambda.

Comment: This in my opinion it is better than all one other solution posted until now

Comment: @RosLuP Why is that, if I may ask?

Comment: Because at last give answers for input > 500000 (if I remember well)

Comment: Suggest `i++<--j` instead of `++i<=--j`

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
ḟo=⁰Σm↑3Ṗİ↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9odXNr///huJ9vPeKBsM6jbeKGkTPhuZbEsOKGlP///zkyNjU)

-2 from DLosc.

Comment: @LuisMendo should be correct now,

Comment: That length filter is expensive. I think "take 3 from each" should work for -2 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///huJ9vPeKBsM6jbeKGkTPhuZbEsOKGlP///zQy)

Answer (score 2):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 117 bytes

```
a=>filter(l=>all(p==p[by-1]for p:map(str,l)),(k=[[i,a-i]for i:1..a-1])+sum([[[i,q,j-q]for q:1..j-1]for i,j:k],[]))[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcwxDsMgDEDRq3S0VROVoQsSuQhioFKRTEgwhAw9PW2izu/rSyu9bCPaEewcOfd3g2znkDOIteJeH6V9LO0mZg0Ce2@UEQkW6xxTUHwhGz1N4VfifT9WcKdVSqpeWk9N/w9TMosn5xHdww9pvHWIoJ@I4ws)

Outputs a solution

Comment: 920 as input not return the output in 1 min in tio... I not speak of 364757698688 but only 920

Comment: @RosLuP That doesn't matter. Efficiency is not an important thing in code-golf. It will theoretically work for all sizes of input so that doesn't matter; given enough time, it will give the correct output for 920.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io),  <s>16 12</s>  10 bytes

```
ef_I#`MT./
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ef_I%23%60MT.%2F&input=15&debug=0)**

### How it works

```
ef_I#`MT./  ~ Full program.

        ./  ~ Integer Partitions.
 f          ~ Filter with a variable T.
     `MT    ~ Map each element of T to a string representation.
    #       ~ Filter.
  _I        ~ Is palindrome? (i.e Invariant over reverse?)
e           ~ Get last element.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
LʒÂQ}U4GXNãDO¹QÏ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f59Skw02BtaEm7hF@hxe7@B/aGXi43/b/f0sA)

---

Outputs the result in three lists as follows:

- Palindromic lists of length 1 (the original number IFF it's palindromic).
- Palindromic lists of length 2.
- Palindromic lists of length 3.

Answer (score 2):

## Axiom, 900 bytes

```
R(x)==>return x;p(r,a)==(n:=#(a::String);if r<0 then(a=0=>R a;n=1 or a=10^(n-1)=>R(a-1);a=10^(n-1)+1=>R(a-2));if r>0 then(n=1 and a<9=>R(a+1);a=10^n-1=>R(a+2));r=0 and n=1=>1;v:=a quo 10^(n quo 2);repeat(c:=v;w:=(n rem 2>0=>v quo 10;v);repeat(c:=10*c+w rem 10;w:=w quo 10;w=0=>break);r<0=>(c<a=>R c;v:=v-1);r>0=>(c>a=>R c;v:=v+1);R(c=a=>1;0));c)
b:List INT:=[];o:INT:=0
f(a:NNI):List INT==(free b,o;o:=p(-1,o);w:=0;c:=#b;if c>0 then w:=b.1;e:=a-o;e>10000000=>R[];if w<e then repeat(w:=p(1,w);w>e=>break;b:=cons(w,b));g:List INT:=[];for i in #b..1 by-1 repeat(b.i>e=>break;g:=cons(b.i,g));if o>e then g:=cons(o,g);n:=#g;for i in 1..n repeat(x:=g.i;x=a=>R[x];3*x<a=>break;for j in i..n repeat(y:=g.j;t:=x+y;t>a=>iterate;t=a=>R[x,y];t+y<a=>break;for k in j..n repeat(z:=t+g.k;z=a=>R[x,y,g.k];z<a=>break)));[])
D(a:NNI):List INT==(free o;p(0,a)=1=>[a];o:=a;for j in 1..10 repeat(t:=f(a);#t>0=>R t);[])
```

test code

```
--Lista random di n elmenti, casuali compresi tra "a" e "b"
randList(n:PI,a:INT,b:INT):List INT==
    r:List INT:=[]
    a>b =>r
    d:=1+b-a
    for i in 1..n repeat
          r:=concat(r,a+random(d)$INT)
    r

test()==
   a:=randList(20,1,12345678901234)
   [[i,D(i)] for i in a]
```

If this code has to decompose the number X in 1,2,3 palindrome, what this code does, it is try near palindrome N < X and decompose X-N in 2 palindrome; if this decomposition of X-N has success return 3 palindrome found; if it fail, it try the prev palindrome G < N < X and try decompose X-G in 2 palindrome etc. Ungolf code (but it is possible some bug)

```
 R(x)==>return x

-- se 'r'=0 ritorna 1 se 'a' e' palindrome altrimenti ritorna 0
-- se 'r'>0 ritorna la prossima palindrome >'a'
-- se 'r'<0 ritorna la prossima palindrome <'a'
p(r,a)==(n:=#(a::String);if r<0 then(a=0=>R a;n=1 or a=10^(n-1)=>R(a-1);a=10^(n-1)+1=>R(a-2));if r>0 then(n=1 and a<9=>R(a+1);a=10^n-1=>R(a+2));r=0 and n=1=>1;v:=a quo 10^(n quo 2);repeat(c:=v;w:=(n rem 2>0=>v quo 10;v);repeat(c:=10*c+w rem 10;w:=w quo 10;w=0=>break);r<0=>(c<a=>R c;v:=v-1);r>0=>(c>a=>R c;v:=v+1);R(c=a=>1;0));c)

b:List INT:=[]   -- the list of palindrome
o:INT:=0         -- the start value for search the first is a

--Decompose 'a' in 1 or 2 or 3 palindrome beginning with prev palindrome of o
--if error or fail return []
f(a:NNI):List INT==
    free b,o
    -- aggiustamento di o, come palindrome piu' piccola di o
    o:=p(-1,o)
    -- aggiustamento di b come l'insieme delle palindromi tra 1..a-o compresa
    w:=0;c:=#b
    if c>0 then w:=b.1 --in w la massima palindrome presente in b
    e:=a-o
    output["e=",e,"w=",w,"o=",o,"#b=",#b]
    e>10000000=>R[]   --impongo che la palindrome massima e' 10000000-1
    if w<e then       --se w<a-o aggiungere a b tutte le palindromi tra w+1..a-o
          repeat(w:=p(1,w);w>e=>break;b:=cons(w,b))
                      -- g e' l'insieme dei b palindromi tra 1..a-o,o
    g:List INT:=[];for i in #b..1 by-1 repeat(b.i>e=>break;g:=cons(b.i,g))
    if o>e then g:=cons(o,g)
    --output["g=",g,b]
    n:=#g
    for i in 1..n repeat
        x:=g.i
        x=a  =>R[x]
        3*x<a=>break
        for j in i..n repeat
           y:=g.j;t:=x+y
           t>a   =>iterate
           t=a   =>R[x,y]
           t+y<a =>break
           for k in j..n repeat
                z:=t+g.k
                z=a =>R[x,y,g.k]
                z<a =>break
    []

--Decompose 'a' in 1 or 2 or 3 palindrome
--if error or fail return []
dPal(a:NNI):List INT==
   free o
   p(0,a)=1=>[a]
   o:=a                  -- at start it is o=a
   for j in 1..10 repeat -- try 10 start values only
        t:=f(a)
        #t>0=>R t
   []
```

results:

```
(7) -> [[i,D(i)] for i in [5,15,21,42,132,345,1022,9265] ]
   (7)
   [[5,[5]], [15,[11,4]], [21,[11,9,1]], [42,[33,9]], [132,[131,1]],
    [345,[343,2]], [1022,[999,22,1]], [9265,[9229,33,3]]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
                                   Time: 0.02 (IN) + 0.02 (OT) = 0.03 sec
(8) -> test()
   (8)
   [[7497277417019,[7497276727947,624426,64646]],
    [11535896626131,[11535888853511,7738377,34243]],
    [2001104243257,[2001104011002,184481,47774]],
    [3218562606454,[3218561658123,927729,20602]],
    [6849377785598,[6849377739486,45254,858]],
    [375391595873,[375391193573,324423,77877]],
    [5358975936064,[5358975798535,136631,898]],
    [7167932760123,[7167932397617,324423,38083]],
    [11779002607051,[11779000097711,2420242,89098]],
    [320101573620,[320101101023,472274,323]],
    [5022244189542,[5022242422205,1766671,666]],
    [5182865851215,[5182864682815,1158511,9889]],
    [346627181013,[346626626643,485584,68786]],
    [9697093443342,[9697092907969,443344,92029]],
    [1885502599457,[1885502055881,542245,1331]], [10995589034484,[]],
    [1089930852241,[1089930399801,375573,76867]],
    [7614518487477,[7614518154167,246642,86668]],
    [11859876865045,[11859866895811,9968699,535]],
    [2309879870924,[2309879789032,81418,474]]]
                                                      Type: List List Any
      Time: 0.25 (IN) + 115.17 (EV) + 0.13 (OT) + 28.83 (GC) = 144.38 sec
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ÅœR.ΔDíQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOvRyUF656a4HF4b@P@/kSEA)

Explanation:

```
Åœ          # integer partitions of the input
  R         # reversed (puts the shortest ones first)
   .Δ       # find the first one that...
     D Q    # is equal to...
      í     # itself with each element reversed
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
ṄṘ‡R⁼c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuYThuZjigKFS4oG8YyIsIiIsIjIxIl0=)

```
ṄṘ‡R⁼c
Ṅ      # Integer partitions (from longest to shortest)
 Ṙ     # Reverse to make the shortest partitions be at the beginning
  ‡  c # Find the first element that satisfies:
   R   #  Reverse each
    ⁼  #  Equal to the original item?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 605 bytes

Prints dupes but they aren't banned afaik

```java
a->{int i=0,j,k,r[]=new int[a-1];for(;i<a-1;r[i]=++i);for(i=0;i<a-1;i++){if(r[i]==a&(""+r[i]).equals(""+new StringBuffer(""+r[i]).reverse()))System.out.println(r[i]);for(j=0;j<a-1;j++){if(r[i]+r[j]==a&(""+r[i]).equals(""+new StringBuffer(""+r[i]).reverse())&(""+r[j]).equals(""+new StringBuffer(""+r[j]).reverse()))System.out.println(r[i]+" "+r[j]);for(k=0;k<a-1;k++)if(r[i]+r[j]+r[k]==a&(""+r[i]).equals(""+new StringBuffer(""+r[i]).reverse())&(""+r[j]).equals(""+new StringBuffer(""+r[j]).reverse())&(""+r[k]).equals(""+new StringBuffer(""+r[k]).reverse()))System.out.println(r[i]+" "+r[j]+" "+r[k]);}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVI9T8MwEJ3Jr7A6oFhpLTowpekAEwNTxyiDSZ3q7MQO/ihCVX57uLpGdCxiwIN193zv3rP0JD/ylRmFlns1wzAa64lEjAUPPeuCbj0YzZ6NdmEQtsyyMbz10JK2586RVw6anLI757lH8Hts86K9OAi7JdiSisx8tT2B9gSqh6VcqqWtm0qLD4JYzVfrpuyMzUvYYF3aGpqqKIBGEBkJh6KgJ@jy@F7x@3yxKM41ZeI98N6d@/POnbegD0@h64T9mbHiKKwTOaV09@m8GJgJno046nsdd170JOrJqCev9HCJ/JNoIsobiPImt8WCpOFoW6FtFW0rtH3tGi/1P9YTUd1AVL/7cyqQVU7TNGMqCZ6UzJTFo4E9GTCf@UWubgi3B0cxriQdDCfjbStGn68faRnxKcum@Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 51 bytes

```apl
{w/⍨⍵=+/¨w←(,y∘.,z),,(z←,∘.,⍨y),y←,x/⍨(⌽≡⊢)¨⍕¨x←⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Tqcv1HvSse9W611dY/tKIcKKKhU/moY4aeTpWmjo5GFVBAB8wFqqrUBEoB@RUgLRqPevY@6lz4qGuR5iGg/qmHVlQA5R71bgaaVfv//6PeVRpAOR11K3WdNLCKzYYGAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 84 bytes

Builds a list of all possible combinations of 3 palindromes from 0 to n, finds the first one whose sum matches, then prunes the zeroes.

```ruby
->n{a=(0..n).select{|x|x.to_s==x.to_s.reverse};a.product(a,a).find{|x|x.sum==n}-[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9curzrRVsNATy9PU684NSc1uaS6pqKmQq8kP77Y1hZC6xWllqUWFafWWifqFRTlp5Qml2gk6iRq6qVl5qVAlBeX5tra5tXqRhvE1v4vUEiLTk8tKQZpzoz9b2lkZgoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 51 bytes

```
{first *.sum==$_,[X] 3 Rxx grep {$_ eq.flip},1..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjRCsIgAAXQX7kMaVsNSTcHQfYRPQUR0oOGY2umBRvit9vO43Haj32eVuwMZI7G@vDFnobfJCVRzf32QIvrsuDltUMkCvpDzWhdahilRKUcniuK7SWiqYiq6TDbd1XigLJOBczscRZgApyh42AtR9ttceQcJ96LS/4D)

- `grep { $_ eq .flip }, 1 .. $_` produces a list of all palindromic numbers from 1 to the input number.
- `3 Rxx` replicates that list three times.
- `[X]` reduces that list-of-lists with the cross-product operator `X`, resulting in a list of all 3-tuples of palindrominc numbers from 1 to the input number.
- `first *.sum == $_` finds the first such 3-tuple that sums to the input number.

Comment: You can [save a byte](https://tio.run/##DcnRCoIwGAbQV/mQkbNktH8qBK3nCCJGF1ssNNcsUGTPvrw9J9jYd3lYsHPQeXU@Tl/sxfQbtGamvl3veEYb@MoM7Ee43odUSyGYqeYZKuXpsaDYUmN1fFPxGv2blzigrFIBN0acW8gWJNEQpCKoZoMjEU7UtZf8Bw) by not reversing the `xx 3`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 62 bytes

```
D,g,@,BDdbR=
D,l,@@,$b+=
D,k,@@*,
L,RÞgdVBcB]Gd‽kdG‽k€bF++A$Þl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HQcfJJSUpyJbLRSdHx8FBRyVJG8TOBrK1dLh8dIIOz0tPCXNKdop1T3nUsDc7xR1EPmpak@Smre2ocnhezv8SK3sulZzE3KSURAVDuxIu////TQE)

~50 bytes golfed while writing up an explanation. Defines a lambda function which returns a list of lists containing the solutions.

### How it works

The last line contains the main function and works by generating all sublists of lengths \$1, 2\$ and \$3\$ containing only palindromic numbers between \$1\$ and \$n\$, then discarding those whose sum does not match \$n\$.

The first section, and helper function, generates the range \$1, 2, ..., n\$, and filters out any number that isn't a palindrome. The helper function `g` is a palindrome checker and `RÞg` filters the range on `g`. We then save this filtered list as \$A\$ for later.

The next section can be split into three further parts:

```
BcB]
Gd‽k
dG‽k€bF
```

The first part takes the array \$A\$ (`[1 2 3 4 ...]`) and wraps each element in an array, yielding `[[1] [2] [3] [4] ... ]`. We then push \$A\$ twice and run the table quick over the function `k`:

```
D,k,@@*,
```

This function does basically nothing. It receives two arguments and wraps them in an array. However, the table quick, `‽` is the magic trick here. It takes two lists and generates every pair of elements between those two lists. So `[1 2 3]` and `[4 5 6]` generates `[[1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [2 4] [2 5] [2 6] [3 4] [3 5] [3 6]]`. It then takes its functional argument (in this case `k`) and runs that function over each pair, which, in this case, simply returns the pairs as is.

After the first two parts are completed, the stack contains a list of wrapped palindromic integers (all palindromic numbers of list length 1), and a list of pairs of numbers that pair each palindromic number with every other palindromic number. The third section pushes the second array again, then pushes \$A\$, and runs the table function over the two arrays. This almost generates the list of triples we need, but annoyingly, each triple has a nested pair. To remove this, we run `€bF` over the list which flattens each sublist. Finally, we concatenate the three lists to form a list of all required sublists.

We've generated all sublists of length \$1, 2\$ and \$3\$ containing palindromic numbers, so all we need to do now is filter those whose sum is not the input. So, we push \$n\$ again and filter each sublist of `l`, which returns whether the sum of the array is equal to \$n\$. Finally, we return the list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 106 bytes

```python
lambda n:[(a,b,n-a-b)for a in range(n)for b in range(n)if all(f'{x}'==f'{x}'[::-1]for x in(a,b,n-a-b))][0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tU1LCsIwEN17igEXTaAF@1Gw0JPULiZ0UgtxWpIoFfHstSqUeABX837z3nj354HzWVen2eBFtQhc1gJjFXOCiZJ6sIDQM1jkjgR/BBUKvQY0RujoMT2jqvreuiyTtHlnpyUb9Mmm3jXL3DrGNHnxz0EJW9DoPNkY0EE7kOPIQ0dMFj29u2AcnOuVIbihuZLbbEbbsxda7KVccRqSLA1IaBRZ@JKHLC9@6nZZaB6zw@LOLw)

In the TIO link I used a faster (but 1 byte longer version) that takes the first valid result as a generator, rather than building the entire list of possible combinations and taking the first.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 334 bytes

```lua
m=math.floor function p(a)a=tostring(a)return a:reverse()==a end
s=io.read()function g(s) for i=s,1,-1 do if(p(m(i)))then
t=i for j=s-i,1,-1 do if (p(m(j)))then u=j for k=t-j,0,-1 do
if(p(m(k))and(k~=0)and((t+u+k)==tonumber(s)))then
print(m(t))print(m(u))print(m(k))return end end end end end end end
if(p(s))then print(s)else g(s)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@9bsMwDIR3PwVHErGDeGgLFODDqDGdyD@SIVEd8@qOICttlw4CTsB3x7slmX1feTV6P4@L9wHG5K5qvYMNDRlWHzVYd8ufIJqCA/MZ5FtCFCRmA@KGJrL15yBmQPqx3zASjDnQcmz7tuth8GBH3HBFS0R6F9co28JMHDv7h4KCTRWDxFPBZtZuai8H1tSwmci4AecHX4pAPaXTnLupd2n9kpCL1HNbXqLZokQvmX5lDqoT86b/3nE11mKHNZIsUcriTOz72/tH/wQ)