# Every positive integer can be written as the sum of 3 palindrome integers. Wha'ts the largest possible palindrome integer for each integer n?

Tags: integer, palindrome

Let `n` be a positive integer then n = a + b + c for some a, b, and c that are palindrome integers. What is the largest possible integer `a` for `k` = 1 to 1_000_000?

Golf this or have the fastest running time.

NOTE: it's NOT the same as this [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146084/yo-boy-must-it-sum) as I am asking for the largest palindrome component. The question just asks for ANY combination.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is currently off-topic. We're hosting programming challenges that require an objective winning criterion. Also, this is potentially a duplicate of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/146084/58563).

Comment: I should also note that there is no explicit win condition present here.

Comment: Note that _duplicate_ should not be interpreted as _exactly the same_ but rather as _trivially portable_.

Comment: _Golf this or have the fastest running time._ I think is not a valid winning criterion.

Comment: @JonathanFrech it's not trivially portable. Finding the maximum component is different to finding ANY combination.

Comment: @JonathanFrech if Golf or fastest is not then what is? I can easily make similiar comments, e.g. your example is not helpful.

Comment: Hi @xiaodai and welcome to PPCG. In terms of winning criteria, the only issue in this case is that challenges typically either have code golf or fastest code as the scoring metric, but not both. You could conceivably create a challenge that uses both metrics but the scoring system would need to be very explicit in that case. That being said, even if a single winning criterion was chosen this challenge is pretty similar to the other challenge referenced which typically counts as a duplicate on this site

Comment: Also, there is a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/75553) on the meta site where people can post their potential questions to see what others think of them. A lot of people use it, even really experienced users who have been on PPCG for a long time

Comment: @xiaodai You can of course state that my _example_ -- I do not know which example you are referring to -- is not helpful. However, this differs from a winning criterion not being valid as the latter -- I think -- is more objectively decidable.

Answer (score 0):

My Julia solution

```
using Base.Iterators

is_palindrome(n) = begin
    dn = digits(n)
    all(dn .== reverse(dn))
end

lim  = Int64(1e6)
res = filter(is_palindrome,lim:-1:0)

using DataFrames
lp = DataFrame(k = 1:1_000_000, largest_palindrome = Array{Int64,1}(lim))

# found stores the integers backwardds
ok(lim, res, lp) = begin
    found = BitArray(lim)
    found .= false
    tot = Int128(0)

    cap = lim
    r = res[1]

    for r in res[1:end-1]
        bs = res[res .<= (cap - r)]
        cs = res[res .<= ceil((cap - r)/2)]

        res1 = vec([r + b + c for (b,  c) in product(bs,cs)])

        res1 = res1[res1 .<= cap]

        for rr in res1
            if !found[rr]
                lp[rr,:largest_palindrome] = r
                tot = tot + r
                found[rr] = true
            end
        end

        for i in lim:-1:1
            if !found[i]
                cap = i
                break
            end
        end
    end

    (tot, found, lp)
end
```